# How to get a continuously data last for how many days?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core

for example:
There is a `datetime` list in the database:

```
   date
2020-08-08
2020-08-07
2020-08-06
2020-08-05
2020-08-02
```

the date last for 4 days continuously.

how can I calculate it?

My expected put is 4 since there is 4 days last continuously.
Is there is a linq or other code to get it?

```
_context.UserDates.Where(...).
```

Comment: Please add your expected output.

Comment: are you looking to "fill in the gaps" for the missing dates in your list?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I added it .

Comment: @Harry No I want to get how many days there is no missing date among them.

Comment: When you run the query.. what do you want to see?  it's still not very clear what you want as an end result from the data set you have shown above!

Comment: @Harry I am sorry. I want to get the day count of the continuously date.I mean the date which has a missing day.I there is 30days which  is every day in a month then it is 30 that continuously.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of ways to achieve this, one fairly readable solution is this

```
--Build test data
;with cteDates as (SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('2020-08-08'),('2020-08-07')
    ,('2020-08-06'),('2020-08-05'),('2020-08-02') ,('2020-08-01')
    ,('2020-07-25') ,('2020-07-24') ) as DateList(ThisDate)
) --Actual code - find the single newest date
,cteFirstInRun as (SELECT TOP 1 ThisDate FROM cteDates ORDER BY ThisDate DESC)
--Find the single newest date that doesn't have one day before in the database
, cteLastInRun as (SELECT TOP 1 D1.ThisDate FROM cteDates as D1 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM cteDates as D2 
            WHERE D2.ThisDate =  DATEADD(day,-1,D1.ThisDate ))
    ORDER BY D1.ThisDate DESC
) --the answer is the difference (in days) between the begining of the run and the end
SELECT F.ThisDate as Newest, L.ThisDate as Oldest
    ,  DATEDIFF(day, L.ThisDate, F.ThisDate) + 1 as RunLength 
FROM cteFirstInRun as F CROSS JOIN cteLastInRun as L
```

It runs on a wide range of server versions, and should be very fast.

Another solution is this - it can give you multiple runs but it only works on newer versions of SQL server (I think 2012 and new, but I'm not sure, it definitely works on 2014). It's a little more complex to understand, but if you need the multiple runs it's worth it

```
--Build test data
;with cteDates as (SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('2020-08-08'),('2020-08-07')
    ,('2020-08-06'),('2020-08-05'),('2020-08-02') ,('2020-08-01')
    ,('2020-07-25'),('2020-07-24'),('2020-07-23') ) as DateList(ThisDate)
), cteRunParts as (SELECT D.ThisDate , 'B' as RunPart   FROM cteDates as D
    WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT * FROM cteDates as D2 WHERE D2.ThisDate = DATEADD(DAY,-1,D.ThisDate))
    UNION ALL
    SELECT D.ThisDate , 'E' as RunPart  FROM cteDates as D
    WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT * FROM cteDates as D2 WHERE D2.ThisDate = DATEADD(DAY,+1,D.ThisDate))
), cteRuns as (SELECT DISTINCT
        CASE WHEN R.RunPart = 'B' THEN R.ThisDate ELSE LAG(R.ThisDate) OVER (ORDER BY R.ThisDate) END as RunStart
        , CASE WHEN R.RunPart = 'E' THEN R.ThisDate ELSE LEAD(R.ThisDate) OVER (ORDER BY R.ThisDate) END as RunEnd
    FROM cteRunParts as R 
) SELECT R.RunStart , R.RunEnd , 1+ DATEDIFF(day, R.RunStart , R.RunEnd ) as RunLength FROM cteRuns as R
```

Note that both of these work on a run of length 1.